# Force SSL for every URL except one path using .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to enforce SSL for every URL except one with the first segment `/preview`.

```
http://test.example.com/preview/blah/blah
```

should be ignored by the rule; every other URL should be forced to use SSL. I'm using CentOS 6.4, Apache, and CodeIgniter.

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/preview/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Normally CI URLs look like this before they are rewritten by the last rule:

```
http://test.example.com/index.php?/preview/blah/blah
```

I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php?/preview/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/preview/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

That doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost had it. The full solution is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/preview
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/preview
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The reason it failed was that `http://test.domain.com/preview/blah/blah` first gets resolved to `http://test.domain.com/index.php?/preview/blah/blah` and that this URL immediately get rewritten again (the htaccess loops with the new URL).

The new URL (`http://test.domain.com/index.php?/preview/blah/blah` did not match your conditions, because the part after the ? is not considered part of the REQUEST_URI, but of the QUERY_STRING. See the description of REQUEST_URI at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Luc. It works great except for one scenario. When my URL is https://testdomain.com/preview.html  it creates redirect loop to https://testdomain.com/preview.html?/preview.html 
Do you know how to fix this?